# Salesforce- Using jQuery to delete table rows using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Right now the error I am getting is Invalid field checked for sObject People_Language__c.

Not sure if it doesn't like the use of the wrapper class or what but I don't see the problem.

Here is the Controller

```
public with sharing class myClass {

    public String pId                                   {get; set;}
    public list<Wrapper>pLanguages                      {get; set;}




    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public myClass(){
         pId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

         pLanguages = new List<Wrapper>();
             for ( People_Language__c pl : [SELECT Id, Language__c, Fluency__c FROM People_Language__c WHERE Person__c=:pId] ) {
               pLanguages.add(new Wrapper(pl));
             }
    }


public void deleteLanguage(){
    List<People_Language__c> langsToDelete = new List<People_Language__c>();
    for ( Integer i = 0; i < pLanguages.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( pLanguages[i].checked ) {
            langsToDelete.add(pLanguages.remove(i--).pl);
        }
    }
    delete langsToDelete;
}

    //WRAPPER
    public class Wrapper {
        public boolean checked {get; set;}
        public People_Language__c pl {get; set;}
    public Wrapper(People_Language__c pl) {
        this.pl = pl;
        this.checked = false; 
    }
}
}
```

visualforce

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Language" id="language"> 
    <apex:inputHidden id="delLanguage" value="{!languagesToDelete}"></apex:inputHidden> 
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">       
         <apex:commandButton id="langNewBtn" value="{!$Label.New}" />
         <apex:commandButton id="LangDel" value="{!$Label.del2}" action="{!deleteLanguage}" rerender="language"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pLanguages}" var="lang" title="People Language">
        <apex:column width = "25px">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!lang.checked}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column styleClass="actionColumn" width = "25px"> 
            <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Action" /> </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputLink styleClass="actionLink" target="_top">Del</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Language" /> </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!lang.pl.Language__c}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Fluency" /> </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!lang.pl.Fluency__c}" />
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery might be useful if you wanted to *hide* the rows from the page, but actually *deleting* them would need to be handled by your Apex controller. Probably the easiest way of doing this is by using a [wrapper class](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) in your controller, and then your `deleteLanguage()` method would be able to loop through and remove any records where the checkbox has been checked. jQuery isn't necessary for this approach.

A simple Apex controller using this approach:

```
public with sharing class PeopleLanguagesController {
    public String pId {get; set;}
    public List<Wrapper> pLanguages {get; set;}

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public PeopleLanguagesController() {
        pId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        pLanguages = new List<Wrapper>();
        for ( People_Language__c pl : [SELECT Id, Language__c, Fluency__c FROM People_Language__c WHERE Person__c = :pId] ) {
            pLanguages.add(new Wrapper(pl));
        }
    }

    public PageReference deleteLanguage() {
        List<People_Language__c> langsToDelete = new List<People_Language__c>();
        for ( Integer i = 0; i < pLanguages.size(); i++ ) {
            if ( pLanguages[i].checked ) {
                langsToDelete.add((pLanguages.remove(i--)).pl);
            }
        }
        delete langsToDelete;
        return null;
    }

    //WRAPPER
    public class Wrapper {
        public boolean checked {get; set;}
        public People_Language__c pl {get; set;}
        public Wrapper(People_Language__c pl) {
            this.pl = pl;
            this.checked = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

And then your VF markup becomes:

```
<apex:page controller="PeopleLanguagesController">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Language" id="language">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
             <!--<apex:commandButton id="langNewBtn" value="{!$Label.New}" />-->
             <apex:commandButton id="LangDel" value="Delete Languages" action="{!deleteLanguage}" rerender="language"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pLanguages}" var="lang" title="People Language">
            <apex:column width = "25px">
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!lang.checked}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column styleClass="actionColumn" width = "25px"> 
                <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Action" /> </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLink styleClass="actionLink" target="_top">Del</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Language" /> </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!lang.pl.Language__c}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Fluency" /> </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!lang.pl.Fluency__c}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Disclaimer: none of this code has been tested, this is just me throwing an example together in Notepad++. Hopefully this puts you on the right track!

**Update**: Okay, I threw together a data model like yours and the updated code compiles and seems to function as intended. You should not be getting the `Invalid field checked for sObject People_Language__c` error on the VF page because this field is part of the wrapper - make sure you have `{!lang.checked}` as the value of the `apex:inputCheckbox` tag, rather than `{!lang.pl.checked}`.

Comment: langsToDelete.add(pLanguages.remove(i--)); Gives incompatible type error wrapper to People_language__c

Comment: Updated my answer, give that a shot now.

Comment: Now I get invalid field "checked" for sObject People_Language__c. I've been stuck on this for over a day.

Comment: What line is throwing the error? I'm not sure if you're using the code I pasted or if you've been using pieces of it, so it may help to update your question with the full code that you're using.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere that would produce that error. Is it giving you a line number? And does this error show up when saving the Apex controller or the VF page?

Comment: it shows up when saving the VF page. The line number is 1 but that's not very helpful.

Comment: One last update to my answer - please see the final revision. I've tested the code/markup posted and it compiles and functions as intended. If this still isn't working for you, let's take it to chat.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to chat. I'm not getting any errors anymore but hitting the delete button does nothing

Comment: I added apexmessages and this is the error I get   "Value 'false' cannot be converted from Boolean to lib.id.ID
"